# checking if entity (properties and collections) are dirty

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have an entity with many one-to-one relations (cascade="all-delete-orphan") and collections.

I want to check is this entity is dirty (including its collections and properties/entities from those one-to-one relations), is there any way to do it?

I following [this](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.aspx) article but it doesnt cover all that I need, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: BTW: I want to do this, to validate if the user can quit the form or if I should warn him of unsaved changes

Answer (score 1):

The `onFlushDirty(...)` method (extends EmptyInterceptor in Hibernate) works for me to check dirty collection. The parent entity with nested collection is passed into onFlushDirty, but I was not aware that the passed-in entity could be the collection element. Once I found that, it worked both for the nested collection and its parent entity.

```
public class PropertyChangeInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{

public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
```

Another method, `onCollectionUpdate(...)` can also be used to catch dirty collection, it gets called after `onFlushDirty(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NHibernate listener, like so:

```
public class AuditUpdateListener : IPostUpdateEventListener
{
    private const string _noValueString = "*No Value*";

    private static string getStringValueFromStateArray(object[] stateArray, int position)
    {
        var value = stateArray[position];

        return value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty
                ? _noValueString
                : value.ToString();
    }

    public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        if (@event.Entity is AuditLogEntry)
        {
            return;
        }

        var entityFullName = @event.Entity.GetType().FullName;

        if (@event.OldState == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("No old state available for entity type '" + entityFullName +
                                            "'. Make sure you're loading it into Session before modifying and saving it.");
        }

        int[] dirtyFieldIndexes = @event.Persister.FindDirty(@event.State, @event.OldState, @event.Entity, @event.Session);

        ISession session = @event.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);

        string entityName = @event.Entity.GetType().Name;
        string entityId = @event.Id.ToString();

        foreach (int dirtyFieldIndex in dirtyFieldIndexes)
        {
            //For component types, check:
            //  @event.Persister.PropertyTypes[dirtyFieldIndex] is ComponentType

            var oldValue = getStringValueFromStateArray(@event.OldState, dirtyFieldIndex);
            var newValue = getStringValueFromStateArray(@event.State, dirtyFieldIndex);

            if (oldValue == newValue)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Log
            session.Save(new AuditLogEntry
                                {
                                    EntityShortName = entityName,
                                    FieldName = @event.Persister.PropertyNames[dirtyFieldIndex],
                                    EntityFullName = entityFullName,
                                    OldValue = oldValue,
                                    NewValue = newValue,
                                    Username = Environment.UserName,
                                    EntityId = entityId,
                                    AuditEntryType = AuditEntryType.PostUpdate
                                });
        }

        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this would be during flushing and thats not what I want. Also I dont think this will go through collections.